# Как правильно писать «По нажатию (или нажатии) кнопки запускается процесс.»?

Tags: орфография, выбор-слов

Как правильно писать «По нажатию (или нажатии) кнопки запускается процесс.»?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант "*по нажатии*" в общем случае неубедителен тем, что такой тип выражения (предлог "по" в значении "после" и соотв. падеж) обычно применяется как указание на **завершение планируемого во времени процесса** (по прибытии = после того, как кто-то находящийся в пути куда-л., закончит его), а не однократного гипотетического действия (которого может и не быть).

В данном случае уместнее "**при нажатии**" (=*в случае нажатия* - указание на условие, при котором происходит то, о чём говорят) или **"по нажатию"** (=*в момент, следующий после нажатия*).

В выражении с "по" используется ограниченный набор глаголов: *по завершении*, *по окончании* процесса (отжига образца - и т. п.), *по истечении* (времени, отведённого на автоматический поиск ошибок). Можно лишь представить себе полуфантастический вариант, что некое механическое устройство (робот) поочерёдно нажимает на кнопки по какой-то программе, и в результате ожидается, что **по нажатии** *всех этих кнопок* (= *после того, как все они окажутся нажатыми*) включится некое устройство - здесь выражение с "по" выглядит вполне уместным (всё происходит после завершения запрограммированных действий).

Answer (score 4):

**По нажатию** - как "по щелчку" вполне приемлемо.

**По нажатии** - "после нажатия" тоже возможно, только такое употребление несколько необычно для  техники, это скорее в выражениях *по окончании, по приезде, по прибытии.*

Процесс может запускаться и *нажатием* кнопки, и *с (момента) нажатия*, и *при нажатии .*